# Browser(browser name) prevented this site(facebook) from opening a pop-up window

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, facebook

I am trying to post some data on facebook after getting a response from the server side.

Example :

```
function share_to_facebook(url){

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/create_data",
    data: data,
    success: function(result) {
      if(result.success=="success"){
        // url contains the facebook url with some required parameters.
        window.open(url, '_blank');
     }
    }
  });
}
```

After executing this method, Getting following message-
"Browser(browser name) prevented this site from opening a pop-up window"

How to open facebook page without getting this errors?

Comment: why do you need the window to open?

Comment: I want to open Facebook URL for sharing a post on facebook

Answer (score 0):

Popup blockers in modern browsers in default settings only let popups go through if they were opened *directly* on user interaction (most often a click.)

But inside the callback function of an async AJAX call, that “direct” connection is lost. The browser sees no connection to the previous user interaction any more, therefor thinks it is an “automated” popup the user did not ask for - and so it gets blocked.

You could try and open the popup window before your AJAX request, with an empty page/`about:blank` as URL (assuming `share_to_facebook` gets called directly on user interaction), and then in your callback you just assign a new URL to the popup window.

```
function share_to_facebook(url){
    var myPopup = window.open('about:blank', '_blank');

    $.ajax({
    // ...
    success: function(result) {
      if(result.success=="success"){
        // url contains the facebook url with some required parameters.
        myPopup.location.href = url;
     }
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply!
But Here we need to open windows if AJAX response is success.

Comment: Not possible directly. But you can close the popup again if it wasn’t a success.